# Hit another page when a specific web page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to insert a thank you page record in google analytical.When I submit a form I want to hit another link so google analytic track it.I don't want to create another page for thank you. So is there any way so when I display thank you message after from submission.I can hit another page with `Javascript` I don't want to load that page just hit that link silently.

Comment: Can you share the link that you want to hit?. Is that google's link or your's?

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: ga('send', 'event', 'Form submission', 'Weekly Sub', 'http://example.com/Thanks'); is a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden button and use it to trigger a hyperlink and access that page silently as you want.If you are not using any HTML and js only then you might call a function which hits that thankyou link of yours.

If you could provide some code it will be helpful to assist you further.

Comment: How i can hit a page silently .I am using html and php and jquery.